# Websphere MQ and version controll

Tags: version-control, ibm-mq

Every change in the production environment has to be versioned and tracked down to specific person who changed it and why.

Is there a possibility to use some tool for that? If not, how to use SVN or GIT for MQ configuration?

What are the best practices for changes in **Websphere MQ** configuration?

I know that all of the configuration lays in the `/var/mqm/qmgrs/QMNAME` directory. But these are not text files, hence simple SVN won't tell me what got changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSphere MQ isn't like a static compiled artifact but rather is a living system that is in part self-managing.  Things like clusters, triggers, instrumentation and even applications all can change settings on MQ objects at run time.

What many shops choose to do is to store the object definitions and authorization control lists in MQSC scripts and keep those files in SVN or other change control system.  Then to capture live changes they enable and monitor [Configuration Events](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/mo10560_.htm) which report details of changes and the user ID that initiated them.

In particular, objects in a WMQ cluster are more volatile at run time and so the scripts should reflect this fact.  The object attributes can be categorized as to whether they are static properties or represent run-time state.  MQSC scripts can take advantage of this by defining the static properties and the dynamic properties in separate steps.  By using the `REPLACE` and `NOREPLACE` options it is possible to write the script so that cluster state is preserved whenever the script is re-run.   This supports a change control methodology of storing all relevant objects in versioned scripts rather than writing a new script for each change to the system.  Capturing the delta between the script versions gives you all the static properties and monitoring and the event messages gives you a view of all changes, including updates to dynamic properties that aren't captured in the scripts.

The 2-step object definition looks like this:

```
* Stateful attributes use NOREPLACE so rerunning the script does not
* reset them to default values at run-time
DEFINE QLOCAL (APP.FUNCTION.SUBFUNCTION.QA) +
       GET(DISABLED) +
       PUT(DISABLED) +
       NOTRIGGER +
       NOREPLACE

* Static values use the REPLACE option to make sure any changes
* are recorded next time the script runs
ALTER  QLOCAL (APP.FUNCTION.SUBFUNCTION.QA) +
       DESCR('APP service queue for QA') +
       DEFPSIST(NO) +
       BOTHRESH(5) +
       BOQNAME('APP.FUNCTION.BACKOUT.QA') +
       CLUSTER('DIV_QA') +
       CLUSNL(' ') +
       DEFBIND(NOTFIXED)
```

There is more detail on this methodology in 
[*Mission:Messaging: Migration, failover, and scaling in a WebSphere MQ cluster*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0811_mismes/0811_mismes.html).